# Do specific mechanics in MTG need their own tags?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

It seems that MTG has a ton of sub-tags that cover very specific categories. Are they really all necessary? I am not referring to alternate formats (as they can be seen as entirely different games), but instead I am referring to stuff like the keyword regenerate and "face down cards." Are they really necessary?

Here are some examples:

- [mtg-regenerate](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-regenerate)
- [mtg-indestructible](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-indestructible)
- [mtg-commander-damage](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander-damage)
- [mtg-planeswalkers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-planeswalkers)
- [mtg-face-down](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-face-down-cards)

Comment: I think they can be useful as they can help to find questions and answers about them.

Comment: See also https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-the-recent-addition-of-mtg-sub-tags