# Rename [priority] to [mtg-priority] and [stack] to [mtg-stack]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Some Magic: the Gathering mechanics have their own tags: [Do specific mechanics in MTG need their own tags?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1832/12315)

They all start with `mtg-`, so can one of the ♦ moderators rename [priority](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/priority) to [mtg-priority](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-priority)?

Even though the [stack](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) tag excerpt and wiki mention other games have that concept as well, [it's currently not used for anything but Magic: the Gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack+-magic-the-gathering) so perhaps it needs to be renamed as well (and the tag wiki/excerpt adjusted).

Comment: Watching, seems like a fine idea.  Will revisit next week if opposing views are minimal.  Thanks.

Comment: So this means we'd have a stack tag for non-MTG question (should the need ever develop) and a stack tag for MTG questions? Is that really a good idea?

Comment: "Priority" in MTG doesn't refer to the common meaning of priority --it means "turn" as in "turn-based"-- so that makes sense.

Comment: Even if there ever is another game with a stack, that game will probably have its own specific mechanics, so it's likely that questions about the MTG stack will not help you understand the other game's stack and vice versa. So I think it would make sense to have multiple [*-stack] tags if that happens. And the [stack] tag has existed for close to 8 years without being applied to a non-MTG question, so it's unlikely that we will actually have to address that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done. I have renamed [priority](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/priority) to [mtg-priority](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-priority) and [stack](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) to [mtg-stack](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-stack). In addition, following this pattern, I have renamed [bestow](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bestow) to [mtg-bestow](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-bestow) and [heroic](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroic) to [mtg-heroic](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-heroic).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the [mtg-priority] tag wiki & excerpt.