# Naming the tag for questions about legendary cards and the legend rule

Tags: discussion, tags, magic-the-gathering

We've got a bunch of questions in MTG around navigating the legend rule, and handling various cases involving legendary permanents in circumstances where the legend rule might apply. I've tagged them to aid discoverability (I'm sure I missed a bunch). I've called the tag [mtg-legendary-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-legendary-cards) and given it this description:

> Questions about handling Legendary cards in light of the Legend Rule in Magic: the Gathering, and questions about the Legend Rule itself.

I feel this tag name may not be ideal as it might imply to people that any question involving a legendary card might warrant the tag. On the other hand I'm worried “legend rule” itself might be a relatively obscure piece of game terminology and thus [mtg-legend-rule] might or might not work.

What should this tag be called? Is [mtg-legendary-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-legendary-cards) fine? Should it be called [mtg-legend-rule] or something else instead?

---

In case you're wondering “why even tag this stuff at all? it's already tagged [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering)”, see [Why the recent addition of MTG sub tags?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/5573) for my reasoning. TL;DR: tagging is making it easier to find questions and duplicates in a topic than text search alone.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about it while drafting up this question — I think maybe we should call it [mtg-legend-rule](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-legend-rule) with [mtg-legendary-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-legendary-cards) as an alias. The legend rule is what these questions are about, and [mtg-legendary-cards] will make the tag more discoverable, but it'll also be clear when the [mtg-legend-rule] tag doesn't actually apply.

The summary could remain the same:

> Questions about handling Legendary cards in light of the Legend Rule in Magic: the Gathering, and questions about the Legend Rule itself.